# How to check if I can send a private message to a user or not using the Facebook API or not?

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook

How to check if I can send a private message to a Facebook user or not using the Facebook API?

The receiver may not necessarily be my friend. Also he hasn't given any rights to my Facebook application.

Edit:
I am using Send dialog for sending private messages to private users but it shows error if the person has disabled to receive private messages.

Answer (score 0):

As I know the FB private messaging has been removed from the public api, I mean that usually apps can't send a private message to FB users, but also as I know you can cooperate with FB to get a special permission for your app, for example in Rockmelt browser you can send private messages, that measn that there is a way to do that, but FB controls that way.

Comment: For now, I don't want to send private messages using API. I just want if the target user have enabled receiving message or not.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more on the sender? Do you require the sender's consent?

Please check if the Send Dialog is what you are looking for
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

AFAIK this is the only way to send private message to an individual. But it requires the user's consent.

You can read more at this similar post:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken